# I am trying to call an async function from a sync callback function (Paramiko Upload Callback) but it fails

Tags: python, python-asyncio, paramiko

```
import os
import paramiko
import asyncio

async def async_websocket_call(msg):
    print(msg)

async def test_paramiko():
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect("web.demo.net", username="root", key_filename=os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + "\\.ssh\\id_rsa")

    def upload_callback(sofar, total):
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        task = loop.create_task(async_websocket_call("Uploaded: {0:.1f}%".format(100*(sofar/total))))
        asyncio.wait(task, timeout=None)
        
    sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
    sftp.put('test.tar.gz', '/var/www/html/test.tar.gz', upload_callback)
    sftp.close()

    ssh.close()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(test_paramiko())
loop.close()
```

I get the error message: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'wait' was never awaited

Well I can't await the wait method because I am not in an async method...

Update:

asyncssh also does NOT seem to be a solution because

asyncssh sftp.put uses a progress_handler of type SFTPProgressHandler:

```
SFTPProgressHandler = Optional[Callable[[bytes, bytes, int, int], None]]
```

So this also does NOT support async callbacks it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after further digging into this the only solution seems to be:

```
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

and

```
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete
```

Comment: Please note that I ran into some trouble with Python 3.10 and it worked again rolling back to Python 3.9.1. The problem was, that the nested calls didn't get properly executed but seem to be put into some sort of queue.